# How to use an Entry contents in a different class?

Tags: python, function, class, tkinter, frames

I hope this is not repetitive, it seems I'm one of the few people who prefers to use Tkinter as Tkinter, not as TK....
So pretty much I'm using classes to make windows. The second window creates a user, but I'm having trouble using that value "username" in a different class.
What am I missing?

(Disclaimer, the windows are ugly, I'm focusing on making the functions work.)
I've tried making the value username a global part of the `clicku()` function.... I've tried making "username" a function under `Startwindow` (with its own definition), I've tried pulling it directly (as shown here)... I've moved it around, tried to work with localities... I'm lost. Would making the entry its own class save this issue...???

```
from tkinter import *


class Window(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self,master,*args,**kwargs)
        self.pack()
        self.pack_propagate(0)
        self.labelone = Label(self, text = "Welcome to our class! Click start to begin")
        self.labelone.grid(row=1,column=1)
        self.buttonone = Button(self, text="start", command=click)
        self.buttonone.grid(row=2,column=1)


class Startwindow(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self,master,*args,**kwargs)
        self.grid(row=5,column=5)
        self.grid_propagate(0)
        self.text = Label(self, text = "What is your name?")
        self.text.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.entry = Entry(self, width=15)
        self.entry.grid(row=1,column=0)
        self.buttontwo = Button(self, text="enter", command=clicku)
        self.buttontwo.grid(row=1,column=1)
        self.username = self.entry.get()



class introwindow(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None,*args,**kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self,master,*args,**kwargs)
        user = str(w2.username)
        self.grid()
        self.grid_propagate(0)
        self.a = Label(self, text = "Aki: ")
        self.a.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        self.sp1 = Label(self, text = "Hi" + w2.username)
        self.sp1.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
        self.sp2 = Label(self, text = "Nice to meet you!")
        self.sp1.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
        self.talk = Entry(self, width = 15)


def click():
    global w2
    w.destroy()
    w2 = Startwindow(root,width=500,height=500)


def clicku():
    w2.destroy()
    w3 = introwindow(root,width=500,height=500)






root = Tk()
w = Window(root, bg="red",width=500,height=500)

root.mainloop()
```

I'm just hoping to make username print in the `introwindow` as part of the `Label` `sp1`.

Comment: Why do you think it's not working? What is it doing? Is it throwing an error? If so, what's the error? If not, what's it doing and how does that differ from what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by creating a global instance of a `tkinter` [`StringVar`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm). Here's doing that to the code posted in your question (which I have also updated to more closely follow the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)).

Your current design doesn't allow making the best use of them (which is why I made it a global variable). But for future reference, here's some [additional information](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/control-variables.html) on how they can be used.

```
from tkinter import *


class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)
        self.pack()
        self.pack_propagate(0)
        self.labelone = Label(self, text="Welcome to our class! Click start to begin")
        self.labelone.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.buttonone = Button(self, text="start", command=click)
        self.buttonone.grid(row=2,column=1)


class StartWindow(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)
        self.grid(row=5,column=5)
        self.grid_propagate(0)
        self.text = Label(self, text="What is your name?")
        self.text.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.entry = Entry(self, width=15, textvariable=username)
        self.entry.grid(row=1,column=0)
        self.buttontwo = Button(self, text="enter", command=clicku)
        self.buttontwo.grid(row=1,column=1)
        self.username = self.entry.get()


class IntroWindow(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self,master, *args, **kwargs)
        self.grid()
        self.grid_propagate(0)
        self.a = Label(self, text="Aki: ")
        self.a.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.sp1 = Label(self, text="Hi " + username.get())
        self.sp1.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.sp2 = Label(self, text="Nice to meet you!")
        self.sp1.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.talk = Entry(self, width=15)


def click():
    global w2
    w.destroy()
    w2 = StartWindow(root, width=500, height=500)


def clicku():
    w2.destroy()
    w3 = IntroWindow(root, width=500, height=500)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = Tk()
    username = StringVar()
    w = Window(root, bg="red", width=500, height=500)

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll look into this. I simplified the global statement and put it directly under the "clicku" command, and that seemed to work when I got it before the window was destroyed (as Brian said in the next comment). Also, is there a name for the underscore name syntax used in the if statement? It would be helpful to understand it more.

Comment: Bryan's suggestion of explicitly retrieving and passing the value on as an argument to the next window is a better approach than making it a global variable. Names that start and end with double-underscores—sometimes called "dunder"—are are "special", often system-defined, variables. `__name__` is a predefined module-level one that is set to the string `"__main__"` when the script has been executed directly by the Python interpreter as opposed to being `import`ed by some other script—in other words it's being used as the main program and not as a module by some other script.

Comment: There's good information and guidelines in [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) on [naming conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions).

Answer (score 0):

Since your entry widget is an attribute of `introwindow`, you simply need to call the `get` method on the entry widget *before* you destroy the window. You can then pass the value to the constructor of the next window

For example, it would look something like this:

```
def clicku():
    name = w2.entry.get()
    print("clickU:", name)
    w2.destroy()
    w3 = IntroWindow(root, width=500, height=500, name=name)
```

Of course, you'll need to modify your `IntroWindow` class to accept the name.

Comment: I got it to work using global, but I did try this method. I was having trouble finding out how to label the argument in the original __init__ parentheses... I'll post it if I figure that method out!